# DependencyProperty data binding returning empty values

Tags: xaml, windows-8, dependency-properties

I am writing a Windows 8 Store App (Metro / Modern?) and I am creating a control to re-use the formatting on multiple forms.  I have created some WPF apps in the past and I attempted to create a Dependency Property the same way that I did in WPF.  When I put the control on a form to use it though, I can't get any value returned.

My personControl.cs WPF class:
  public partial class PersonControl : UserControl
      {

```
    public PersonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("thisPerson", typeof(Person), typeof(PersonControl));

    public Person thisPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PersonProperty, value);
        }
    }

}
```

for the windows 8 app it requires PropertyMetadata to be added -- I'm assuming that this is where I am going wrong, but I haven't been able to track down what to do instead:

public partial class PersonControl : UserControl
      {

```
    public PersonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("thisPerson", typeof(Person), typeof(PersonControl), new PropertyMetadata(new Person()));

    public Person thisPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PersonProperty, value);
        }
    }

}
```

---

nothing has changed in the usage or binding of the control in the XAML that I know of.  I am still using sample data so I create a List(Person) and then make a listbox and bind the listbox to the List(Person).

---

here is the binding code:

On the usercontrol xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name=”PersonGrid”>
…….
<TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=thisPerson.FirstName, ElementName=This}"></TextBox>
```

On the mainpage Xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="layoutRoot">        
   <ListBox x:Name="myListbox">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <local:PersonControl x:Name="myControl" thisPerson="{Binding Path=.}" Margin="5"></local:PersonControl>               
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Main page code behind:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
… populate data … 
myListbox.ItemsSource = People;
```

---

As an additional note -- when I take the contents of the UserControlXaml and put the UI elements directly into the XAML on the main page, it works fine -- it is when I use the UserControl that it fails.

Comment: What is the binding that you're using?

Comment: edited original to show how I bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the line in XAML on the usercontrol:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=thisPerson.FirstName, ElementName=This}">
```

doesn't work the same in Windows 8 -- when I took out the reference to the ElementName and the DependencyProperty (and just let .Net figure that out on it's own I guess?) it worked fine.

so:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
```

works fine and the Binding is functional now.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the SetProperty call only causes a change to be registered if the value is different than the default value.  Again, IIRC, SetProperty does not compare actual objects, just if a reference to the object has been set or not (object.Equals vs. object != null).  By using this code...

```
new PropertyMetadata(new Person()));
```

the SetValue does not work as you expect because it has an object, and assigning a new one does not result in the property updating.  Change to

```
new PropertyMetadata(null)
```

and I think things will work correctly.

Kinda rushed so maybe I have missed something...

Comment: I attempted this and didn't get any better results.  Thanks for the tip though